# Now with Gnome in Ubuntu 18.04 how to Integrate wine systray with real one

Tags: gnome, wine, 18.04

I have recently upgraded to ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I installed wine and a couple of wine applications.

Now when a wine windows program attempts to make a systray icon, a new window appears:

[image]

How can I integrate these icons into the top row icons next to the wifi, skype etc..

[image]

Update: Similar questions have pointed at loading an indicator tray gadget but that is unity specific. Now that ubuntu has gone gnome, that option no longer works :(

Update: I've tried to install appIndicator package, but couldn't find it..

Comment: Please do not bump your question with pointless edits. If you want to get more attention, [set a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/bounty).

Comment: sadly, i cant afford a bounty with my low rep :'(, i dont have any other way to bump my question

Comment: Use this GNOME extension: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/495/topicons/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many thanks to Ali for his Comment.

Use this GNOME extension: [extensions.gnome.org/extension/495/topicons](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/495/topicons)

This works for me.

Answer (score 4):

#### You can use the [Tray Icons](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1503/tray-icons/) extension by [zhangkaizhao](https://extensions.gnome.org/accounts/profile/zhangkaizhao).

TopIcons, which [sjuk's earlier answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1212180/22949) recommends, doesn't work anymore.

Tray Icons is based on an older extension, TopIcons Plus, which is similar to TopIcons. As the [Tray Icons README](https://github.com/zhangkaizhao/gnome-shell-extension-tray-icons) says:

> ## Tray Icons
>
> Simple version of [TopIcons
> Plus](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1031/topicons/).
>
> Base on TopIcons Plus v22 from [GNOME Shell
> Extensions](https://extensions.gnome.org/).
>
> Keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: I've been trying to solve this problem with Wine for a couple of years now, including following and interacting with threads on their issue tracker, and this fixed the problem in 30 seconds. Thank you so much! For anyone else reading, here's how to install a GNOME extension that you just downloaded: https://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2017/11/how-to-install-manually-gnome-shell-extension.html

Comment: Inbetween, I've found out that this "Tray icon" extension was causing a massive CPU overload through the gnome-shell process, has anyone found a non-buggy extension now ?

Comment: I'm gonna try this one https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2890/tray-icons-reloaded/ , it seems to be stil recieving code updates